# array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, clang++

What type should I use to it compile for `s` parameter in the constructor? I tried `unsigned char s[32]` and `unsigned char *s` but both give compiler error:

> array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal

```
struct foo
{
    size_t a;
    size_t b;
    unsigned char c[32];

    constexpr foo(size_t a_, size_t b_, ??? s) : 
        a(a_), 
        b(b_), 
        c(s)
    { 
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `std::array<unsigned char, 32>`

Comment: What did you actually pass when calling the constructor?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Actually, I want to do same as C99's `{.a = x, .b = y, .c = z }` but C++ didn't have such a feature I neeeded to use the constructor.

Comment: Are you talking about [tag:c11] [unnamed field](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html#Unnamed-Fields) initializers?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Nope. C99 designated initializer

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731707/why-does-c11-not-support-designated-initializer-list-as-c99

Comment: @TheMask THX 4 clarfying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing you could use is variadic template:

```
struct foo
{
    size_t a;
    size_t b;
    unsigned char c[32];

    template<typename ... UnsignedChar>
    constexpr foo(size_t a_, size_t b_, UnsignedChar ... s) : 
        a(a_), 
        b(b_), 
        c{s...} //use curly braces here
    { 
    }
};
```

And then use it as:

```
foo f(10, 20, 1,2,3,4,5, .....,32);
     //a,  b, -------s-----------
```

Note that if you pass less than 32 values for the third argument `s`, the rest of the elements of `c` will be initialized with `0`, and if you pass more than 32 values, the compiler (I guess) will give warning (or error!).

Or use `std::array<unsigned char, 32>` instead of `unsigned char[32]`.

Comment: @0x499602D2: `struct array { unsigned char data[32]; };` would work in C++03. That is, wrap the array in a struct, or create your own array container just like `std::array`.

Comment: Yeah, remember there's `boost::array`.

Comment: what compiler are you using and is there nonstandard C++ in your code? I get a lot of error on clang++ 3.3: `error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'char' to 'unsigned char' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
                c{s...}` one error for each `s`' argument.

Comment: I figured it out: s isn't compatible to C: `char` and `unsigned char`. I need to keep `c` as `unsigned`. can I do it work?

Comment: And `f(10, 20, 1)` doesn't work because argument #3 isn't `char` but `int` and it result into compiler error

Comment: @TheMask: Instead of `c{s...}`, write `c{static_cast<unsigned char>(s)...}`. That should work.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it but I didn't knew it could work to an array. Some C++ stuff are still confusing to me. I come from C...

Comment: Your solution is so amazing I ended up without use a single macro or complex templates to do my implementation. Thanks very very much!