# Initialization of a typedef like a struct

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

Here is a code snippet:

```
typedef struct foo {
    int i;
    int o;
} foo;

int main() {
    foo bar2 = {
        .i = 42;
        .o= 24;
    };
    foo bar1;
    bar1.i = 42;
    bar1.o = 24;
}
```

I am trying to initialize the variable `bar2` within the declaration, but it didn't work. But the initialization of the struct `bar1` works pretty fine.
Can Anybody tell me why the initialization of `foo2` gives a SyntaxError?

Comment: foo2? what foo2? Also, designated initializers are not C++.

Comment: Sorry but you forgot to mention the 5 other errors with the code...

Comment: Sorry I mentioned bar2, ... going to edit this.

Comment: You're trying to write C++ using C syntax, why? If you want to write C, then write C. If you want to write C++, then write C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initializer elements must be separated with a comma, not a semicolon,
However while C (since C99) supports designated initializers,  standard C++ does not support it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731707/why-does-c11-not-support-designated-initializer-list-as-c99).

You can do:

```
foo bar2 = { 42, 24 };
```

Some C++ compilers might support such a designated initializer list, which comes from C, as an extension - in which case the syntax would be:

```
foo bar2 = {.i = 42, .o= 24};
```

Comment: Ok, thanks alot, so there where two faults:
First: I mistyped and seperated by comma instead of semicolon.
Second: I'm used to C and not C++. But in this case I had to use C++ and I didn't know that this initialization is not supported.
Thank You!