# C lookup string by value

Tags: c

I need to translate a value into a human readable string. Normally for things *I* define I would use values that start at zero and create a simple array of strings with the values as the index.

```
static const char *foo[] = { "foo", "bar", "etc" };
if (val < 3) printf("%s\n", foo[val]);
```

For this circumstance I have values that do not start at zero and there are some gaps between them. Is there a good way to do this without having to manually code in a bunch of empty strings for the indexes without a matching value/string pair?

```
static const char *foo[] = { "", "", "", "foo", "", "bar", "", "", "etc" };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of C99, you can use [designated initialisers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html):

```
static const char *foo[] = { 
   [3] = "foo", 
   [5] = "bar",
   [8] = "etc"
};
```

This is equivalent to the array definition you posted and will generate an array with 9 entries. There is a similar syntax for the initialisation of structs:

```
struct Person joe = {
    .name = "Joe", .age = 24, .favcolor = "mauve"
};
```

Note that this is a C feature only and [will not work in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731707/why-does-c11-not-support-designated-initializer-list-as-c99).

Comment: This is what I have been doing but when referencing an index we didn't define, like 4 in your example, it returns null. My concern is this unsafe behavior; is this ok and I just need to handle the nulls appropriately?

Comment: Yes, it is safe. Uninitialised values are initialised to a null or zero value, in your case the `NULL` pointer. The gaps are treated in the same way as trailing uninitialised elements are: In `int a[3] = {2, 5};` the value of `a[2]` is guaranteed to be 0.

Comment: (Note: My suggestion is only a nicer representation of your solution. It essentially creates the same array, including a lot of empty entries. If you need a sparse array with index-value pairs, you have to implement that explicitly.)

Answer (score 3):

If there aren't too many gaps, you can encode each contiguous sequence as a separate array, and then do a little bounds-checking to find the appropriate one to use.  Here's a quick-and-dirty example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const int array_first_indices[] = {3, 15, 28, 32};
static const char * array0[] = {"foo"};
static const char * array1[] = {"bar", "baz"};
static const char * array2[] = {"bloop", "blorp", "blat"};
static const char * array3[] = {"glop", "slop", "bop"};

#define check_array(whichArray, idx) { \
   unsigned int relIdx = idx - array_first_indices[whichArray]; \
   if (relIdx < (sizeof(array##whichArray)/sizeof(const char *))) \
      return array##whichArray[relIdx]; \
   }

const char * LookupWord(int idx)
{
   check_array(0, idx);
   check_array(1, idx);
   check_array(2, idx);
   check_array(3, idx);
   return NULL;
}

int main(int args, char ** argv)
{
   for (int i=0; i<50; i++) printf("   LookupWord(%i) = %s\n", i, LookupWord(i));
   return 0;
}
```

For a fully general lookup mechanism, you'd probably need to use a data structure like a hash table or a tree; C implementations of those data structures are available, although if you have the option of using C++ it would be easier to use those data structures in that language, as they are provided by the standard library.

Comment: A little more than what I need for this situation but i'll file that one away. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a sorted array that maps IDs to strings and use the `bsearch()` function to look up the string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct id_msg_map {
    int id;
    char const* str;
};


int comp_id_string( const void* key, const void* element)
{
    int key_id     = ((struct id_msg_map*) key)->id;
    int element_id = ((struct id_msg_map*) element)->id;

    if (key_id < element_id) return -1;
    if (key_id > element_id) return  1;
    return 0;
}

static struct id_msg_map msg_map[] = {
    {3, "message 3"} ,
    {12, "message 12"},
    {100, "message 100"},
    {32000, "message 32000"},
};

#define ELEMENTS_OF(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))
char const* get_msg(int x)
{
    struct id_msg_map key = {x};
    struct id_msg_map* msg = bsearch(&key, msg_map, ELEMENTS_OF(msg_map), sizeof(msg_map[0]), comp_id_string);

    if (!msg) return "invalid msg id";

    return msg->str;
}

void test_msg(int x)
{
    printf("The message for ID %d: \"%s\"\n", x, get_msg(x));
}

int main(void)
{
    test_msg(0);
    test_msg(3);
    test_msg(100);
    test_msg(-12);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use designated initialisers, as described in [M. Oehm's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30365029/1989425), but that silently introduces the same gaps you were referring to earlier (with implicit `0` values). That option is most suitable when you know `0` will never be an actual selection, when the table doesn't change dynamically (particularly in size) and when the size of the table is small.

---

If the table is particularly large, but items are never added or removed from it you can use [`qsort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html) and [`bsearch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/bsearch.html) on a key/value-pair style structure. For example:

```
struct foo_pair {
     int key;
     char *value;
};

int foo_pair_compare(void *x, void *y) {
    struct foo_pair *a = x, *b = y;
    return (a->key > b->key) - (a->key < b->key);
}

int main(void) {
    struct foo_pair foo[] = { { .key = 3, .value = "foo" },
                              { .key = 5, .value = "bar" },
                              { .key = 6, .value = "etc" } };

    /* qsort needs to be done at the start of the program,
       and again each time foo changes */
    qsort(foo, sizeof foo / sizeof *foo, sizeof *foo, foo_pair_compare);

    /* bsearch is used to retrieve an item from the sorted array */
    struct foo_pair *selection = bsearch(&(struct foo_pair) { .key = 5 },
                                         foo, sizeof foo / sizeof *foo,
                                         sizeof *foo, foo_pair_compare);
}
```

---

When items are routinely added or removed from the collection, it will make more sense to select a hashtable or some kind of ordered map. If you can't be bothered writing and testing your own of these collections, I imagine there are plenty of tried & tested libraries on the internet that you could check out.