# Alternative to designated initializers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, declaration, c99

The style of code using designated initializers below belongs to C language

```
 int widths[] = { [0] = 1, [10] = 2, [100] = 3 };
```

I would like to know, is there some way to write such a simple code in C++?

Comment: You mean C99 maybe ?

Comment: Yves Daoust, yes I do.

Comment: Using the correct term (designated initializers) would massively help searchability. And yes, you can translate this to C++, but the *actual* C++ way of writing the code would be to create a class with the appropriate logic in its constructor, not by using a raw array.

Comment: @CodyGray There is no any need to create a class that to use an array.:) It is just a silly idea to create a class for using an array.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Some already created that class, it is called `std::vector`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Designated initialisers are a standard C feature. There is only one valid C standard (and yes, it was introduced with C99).

Comment: @Lundin You are wrong. You are trying to substitute one question for another. If I will need to use either std::vector, or std::array or some other container then I will use it. But I will not create a class that to use an array.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow How am I wrong? Someone didn't create `std::vector`?

Comment: @Lundin As I said  it looks like you are trying to substitute one question for another question.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Aaah, now I see! Half-past twelve.

Comment: @Lundin By the way after a couple of days I can become a great specialist on arrays.:)

Comment: Additional information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731707/why-does-c11-not-support-designated-initializer-list-as-c99

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ you have to write

```
int widths[101] = { 1 };
widths[10]  = 2;
widths[100] = 3;
```

Comment: @PreferenceBean  Yes, there is no straightforward approach to initialize an array the same way as the C allows.