# Will modern C++ ever support C# "Object Initalizer" Syntax?

Tags: c++, c++20

I was curious if the modern c++ standards people have considered or added the "Object Initializer" syntax of C#.  For example, in C# I can initialize the members of an object like this during initialization:

```
StudentName student2 = new StudentName
{
    FirstName = "Craig",
    LastName  = "Playstead"
};

public class StudentName {
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
};
```

Would be really handy if the standards people had planned to add "object initializer" syntax this to modern C++, ie. C++11, C++14, C++17, C++20, etc...

Does it currently exist in the modern C++ specification?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45772324/2189130) says there's a C++20 proposal for C-style designated initializers, but its not the same as C#

Comment: That is not valid Java.

Comment: How is this any any way superior to using a constructor: `new StudentName(  "Craig", "Playstead" )` ?

Comment: @NeilButterworth I think your example already showcased that. In the case where a class is only a bag of variables, and especially if they have common types, having a name for them is nice. How did you know it _wasn't_ `new StudentName("Playstead", "Craig")`?

Comment: @Passer None of my classes are "bags of variables". And how did you know that it wasn't `FirstName = "Playstead", LastName  = "Craig"`? Both have just as much type-checking.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I meant when type-checking doesn't help you in preventing misordering the parameters, having names for them are nice.

Comment: @Passer Maybe it's just me - but I have to say for me that it is a non-problem. I'm not boasting, but I really cannot remember a case where I got the parameters of the same type reversed. Of course, it's maybe not harmful to have this feature added, but I tend to think that C and C++ should diverge. For example, VLAs should never be part of C++ (or C, IMHO),

Comment: @NeilButterworth It depends on the circumstance. Consider if you were using a date library, and you write `Date{day, month, year}` to construct a Date, where the variables are integers. Can you be sure that's correct? Why shouldn't it be `Date{month, day, year}` or `Date{year, month, day}`? It's easy to get wrong, and it's easy to miss if you get it wrong

Comment: @Justin I would argue it's just as easy to get it wrong and miss it with named parameters. Unless the compiler can spot it wit a strong type-system, all this really does is add more necessary complexity to the language without providing any type safety. And now I have to go and shout at a squirrel that is attacking my bird feeder.

Comment: "That is not valid Java."  two points for C#

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). They've been around in C since C99 but weren't added to C++. Now they are planned to be added in C++20, with some limitations though. Example:

```
struct db_config
{
    std::string host = "localhost";
    std::string port = "5432";
    std::string dbname;
    std::string user;
    std::string password;
} config = {
    .dbname = "test",
    .user = "admin",
    .password = "v3ry$3cur3"
};
```

Some compilers however (e.g. GCC) already allow the use of C designated initializers in C++ code as an extension.